# (missing) Corrupted LFS files with the Gitea server down

Tags: git, git-lfs

I've lost my Gitea server, and I've built a new one. However, when I try to push my local repository, I encounter numerous LFS corrupted files.

Below is a log from an attempt to push my local repository to a local git bare repository.

```
> git remote set-url origin D:/temp/newtest/newrepo.git/
> git push --all
Git LFS upload missing objects:323/10336), 0 B | 0 B/s
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (10323/10336), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
  (missing) Content/StarterContent/Architecture/Floor_400x400.uasset (3467facaefe26eae3ffc1ea62baa8c7b24a8a75c44a30177ccb698434364e104)
  (missing) Content/StarterContent/Particles/P_Ambient_Dust.uasset (ec8f76845d16812584e400c350caffe80b18db8c6577cae0c9e7bb2233b2d4a4)
  (missing) Content/StarterContent/Blueprints/Blueprint_CeilingLight.uasset (62d7f4322c694a4796eebd2b34991a23746a735eda40399a9a11b77ef12dbe8f)
[...]

Enumerating objects: 18587, done.
Counting objects: 100% (18587/18587), done.
Delta compression using up to 20 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (13327/13327), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18587/18587), 661.14 MiB | 152.96 MiB/s, done.
Total 18587 (delta 4978), reused 18583 (delta 4975), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4978/4978), done.
To D:/temp/newtest/newrepo.git/
 * [new branch]        develop -> develop
 * [new branch]        master -> master
```

Is there any solution to would save my history and repository considreing that:

- My local data is fine (I can buid the Unreal project and everything is fine)
- I tried `git fsck` and `git lfs fsck` with no success
- I tried `git config  lfs.allowincompletepush true` but it push inconsistent repository (max 18GB on the 32GB of content)
- I tried `git lfs checkout` with no luck
- `git add --renormalize path/to/file` did not helped

As mentioned, I would like to push the repository again to a new server. I'm open to a solution that would lose the history of the affected files (but not the full history) nor the files themselves.